# HOW to deploy a MERN APP to production, without using firebase or heroku or aws

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, web-hosting

So people, I'm planning to build a website with MERN Stack and host it from my local machine. How to do that without using aws or fire base.

How to use my machine as Backend and database(express, node and mongodb hosted in local host) for the react frontend (hosted in [www.someurl.com](http://www.someurl.com)).

PS: I have already created a site using firebase and firestore as backend.
https://t-heros.web.app/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One thing is you need to keep your local machine 24*7 for your app to work throughout the day. And for your answer you can expose your localhost to public domain by using static IP address and routing applicable from your router with appropriate firewall rules, all this also requires effort and maybe static IP address requires purchase. With both these together your React app can access the localhost on your machine for operations.